# Use Camera & Photo Album

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera

I am trying to have a button that is meant to open the camera and a button that is meant to open camera roll. Here is my code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)getCameraPicture:(id)sender{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.allowsEditing = NO;
    picker.sourceType = (sender == takePictureButton) ?
    UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera : UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
}

- (IBAction)selectExistingPicture {
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {
        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.allowsEditing = NO;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    }else{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry" message:@"Device does not support photo library" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}

- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {
    imageView.image = image;
}



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
        takePictureButton.hidden = YES;
    }
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Any ideas on why it's not working? Everything is linked but the buttons do nothing

Thanks

***EDIT***

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UIButton *takePictureButton;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *takePictureButton;

- (IBAction)getCameraPicture:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)selectExistingPicture;

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add :

```
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

at the end of your 'getCameraPicture:' and in your 'selectExistingPicture:'.

And you also might want to add the 'UIImagePickerControllerDelegate' to your view controller's interface so the 'didFinishPickingImage' gets called.

Edit :

You should replace your :

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo;
```

with

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

beccause that method is long deprecated.

Use it like this :

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    self.imageView.image = chosenImage;

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Code from http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-camera-iphone-app/.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My camera opens now but the imageView doesn't change to the photo I've taken... Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks again. Everything is working now it's just my chosen image isn't showing and the image from the camera is showing. Everything else is fine now

Comment: Can you check my answer to put this question as resolved ? thx

Comment: where is your 'imageView' instanciated ?

Comment: I have got IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView; in my ViewController.h

Comment: Yes. Both IBActions are linked to the correct buttons & my UIImageView is linked @Rom

Comment: I added it into my question

Comment: What's the uiimageview 's frame ?